# Rails - ActionController::Parameters to string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

There are two params and am getting a single one like that

```
v = (params.require(:service).permit(:title))
```

This v has a value like this `{"title"=>"test,kil"}` and I want to get the value of right side to a string, but all in vain. 
The concept am trying to impose after that i will have `@test= "test,kil"`

Anyhelp will be great full. am a newbie to Rails.

Comment: You can drop the parens around `(params.require(:service).permit(:title))` unless you want pretend it's LISP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`params` in Rails is just a Hash (well kind of).

To access the values of a hash in Ruby you use the square bracket syntax:

```
v = params.require(:service).permit(:title)
@test = v['title']
```

Params in Rails are a kind a special hash type called `HashWithIndifferentAccess`. So we can do both `v['title']` or `v[:title]`.

Comment: Normal ruby hashes are specific about the type of a key. `{ "a" => 2 }[:a]` returns nil for example.

Comment: further more i am going to split the @test into array after every "," break and then can i pass it to Service.new(@test) in a loop?
i.e `@again = @test.try(:split,",")
@again.each do |kil|
    Service.new(kil)
 end`

Comment: I'm not sure what you asking. Its usually better to [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) than to comment with a bunch of follow up questions that don't directly relate to the original question.

Comment: Okay am going to post a new question @max

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31366187/rails-passing-arrays-as-params-in-model-function
answer @max

Answer (score 0):

You can just do the following:

```
@test = params.require(:service).permit(:title)[:title]

def create
  @qure = params.require(:service).permit(:level_id)[:level_id]
  @test = params.require(:service).permit(:title)[:title]
  @gain = @test.split(",")

  # Note: You need to use a hash to pass args to the model
  @gain.each do |fil|
    Service.create!(title: fil, level_id: @qure)
  end

  redirect_to root_url
end
```

I've also used create! in the method but you should consider using save and checking the return value if you want to use validations. The above will raise an error if there are validation issues.

Comment: Sorry to ask again can i Split @test into array and then pass it through `Service.new(@test)`, as param?

Comment: Yes, you can just split with @test.split(",") and this will give you an array. Is Service an active record object? What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Service is an Model. can i pass it to `Service.new(@test) in a loop? i.e @again = @test.try(:split,",") @again.each do |kil| Service.new(kil) end`

Comment: Kindly Look at here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31366187/rails-passing-arrays-as-params-in-model-function

Comment: OK so you can't just pass strings to new. I mad an error in my previous comment as I was rushing but you can pass ids to find as an array which is different.

To use new you need to pass a hash! I'll update my answer to reflect

Comment: Kindly update it to actual question so that i can Tick it right there