# Rails - Passing Arrays as Params in Model Function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

for_tag has two attributes, 1: `:level_id` 2: `:title`. 
User is entering both values but in `:title`, entering values as

> Math,English,ETC
>   and am splitting this into array as

```
@test = params.requrie(:service).permit(:title)[:title]
```

I need to create entering in DB with the same `:level_id`

```
title:math,level_id:1
title:English,level_id:1
```

in my Service Controller am trying this.

```
def create
    @qure = params.require(:service).permit(:level_id)[:level_id]
    @test = params.require(:service).permit(:title)[:title]
    @gain = @test.split(",")

    @gain.each do |fil|
      Service.new(fil,@qure)
    end

    redirect_to root_url
  end
```

this giving me an error

> When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.

my Migration

```
def change
    create_table :services do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.integer :level_id

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
```

Comment: `@test = params.requrie(:service).permit(:title)[:title]` typo in require. You need to use strong params usually in a `service_params` private method.

Comment: See my answer to similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31365644/rails-actioncontrollerparameters-to-string/31365721#31365721

Comment: You can see my solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31365644/rails-actioncontrollerparameters-to-string/31365721?noredirect=1#comment50714000_31365721

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do the following:

```
@test = params.require(:service).permit(:title)[:title]

def create
  @qure = params.require(:service).permit(:level_id)[:level_id]
  @test = params.require(:service).permit(:title)[:title]
  @gain = @test.split(",")

  # Note: You need to use a hash to pass args to the model
  @gain.each do |fil|
    Service.create!(title: fil, level_id: @qure)
  end

  redirect_to root_url
end
```

I've also used create! in the method but you should consider using save and checking the return value if you want to use validations. The above will raise an error if there are validation issues.

Comment: It worked a perfect answer but why you used CREATE! instead of NEW?

Comment: New doesn't actually save to the database. If you use new you also have to call save afterwards. Like: service = Service.new; service.save